# Write access violation exception

Tags: c++, stack

I'm making this program where you have to use a switch statement in a main to modify a stack, and I'm having a little problem with the push statement. After I input the value to put on the stack, the program pauses and shows this error:
`Exception thrown: write access violation.
**this** was 0x1AD0112. occurred`
The error points to my cpp file for the methods under push().

```
#include "Stack.h"

void Stack::push(int val) {
    top = top + 1;
    ary[top] = val;          //this is where the exception is thrown.
    //ary[top++] = val;
}

int Stack::pop() {
    top = top - 1;
    return ary[top + 1];
    //return ary[top--];
}

    int Stack::peek() const {
        return ary[top];
    }

    bool Stack::isFull() const {
        if (top == SIZE - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        //return top == SIZE - 1;
    }

    bool Stack::isEmpty() const {
        if (top == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        //return top == -1;
    }

    Stack::Stack() {
        top = -1;
    }
```

And then I call the method in the main to put the value at the top of the stack.

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Stack s;
    int x;
    int y;
    char c;

    cin >> c;

    do {

        switch (c) {
        case 'P':           //push statement
            cin >> x;
            s.push(x);
            break;

        //case 'O':
            //y = s.pop();
            //cout << y << endl;
            //break;

        case 'K':
            y = s.peek();
            cout << y << endl;
            break;

        case 'Q':
            return 0;
            break;

        }

    } while (c != 'Q');
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file as well

```cpp
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

class Stack {
    private:
        int top;
        static const int SIZE = 10;
        int ary[SIZE];

    public:
        int pop();
        void push(int);
        int peek() const;
        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool isFull() const;
        Stack();

};

#endif
```

The error occurs after putting in the first push value. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Why have you not posted Stack.h?

Comment: @Mat You beat me by seconds.

Comment: @NeilButterworth That would probably be a good idea. Just put it in. Thanks

Comment: Well, what should happen if you push onto a full stack?

Comment: @alterigel It adds another element onto the stack whenever it pushes, right?

Comment: @JohnSmith Stop tagging your code with these tags that make a "run" thingy show up when your code (single .h, .cpp-file) can't run anyway.

Comment: @JohnSmith but your array is only of size 10. What should happen if you push more than 10 elements into the array?

Comment: @alterigel maybe throw a `stackoverflow()`-exception? \*duck 'n run\*

Comment: At the point of the crash, look at `top` and `ary`. Are they valid? People have noticed that your `case 'P'` doesn't check `isFull` and your `case 'K'` doesn't check `isEmpty` - in both cases you have buffer overflow/underflow.

Comment: @RaymondChen Okay, so I added `while (!s.isFull())` to before you input the value and `while (!s.isEmpty()) to before the `y = s.peek();` and after it calls the K case, it just stops. I can't type anything else in. The exception is gone, though

Comment: @JohnSmith -- You do know that a simple two line program totally messes up?  `{Stack s; s.peek();}`.  Before you put menus around broken classes, test your class by pushing, popping, peeking, hard-coded values.

Comment: Got it figured out, guys. Thanks so much!

Comment: Why did you choose a `while` loop? Do you want to keep repeating the `push` until the stack is full? That's not normally how people use a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only place where you can change the value of 'c' which is used in the switch case statement is before the "do while loop", you end up in in the loop stuck with the selection you made. In case you chose 'P' all values you type later on are the ones you want to push to the stack (because you are stuck with c = 'P') Move the cin >> c line inside the 'do' part before the 'switch' statement. This will make the program behave more like you planned it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out just before you answered. Thank you, though